# Visual Studio 2022: "Task List" window is empty when VS starts

Tags: visual-studio

Found several similar questions for older VS versions, some especially mentioning C++.
I'm getting the effect with C# as well as VB.Net projects in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.3.3

Steps to reproduce:

- Open a new VS2022 IDE instance
- "Create new Project", say type "ASP.Net Core Web App (C#)" or a "Console App (Visual Basic)"
- Open the View -> "Task List" window
- Open any code file, e.g. WebApplication1\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs
- In C# add a line

```
    //TODO: find this in the IDE's "Task List" window // in the OnGet() event handler
    ' Or TODO: something ' in VB.Net code
```

- Observed: the TODO line appears in the Task List window as expected //Okay
- Save, and close the IDE instance
- Open a the same newly created "WebApplication1" solution in a new VS IDE instance.
- Observed: Task List window is empty although the TODO line still exists // not Okay
- As soon as one edits any code file, e,g. WebApplication1\Pages\Error.cshtml.cs, even by just adding and removing a single space
- Observed: unexpectedly (all if there are more than just one) TODO lines magically reappear in the Task List

**Actual question:**
Is that a reproducible VS Bug or is it just me / my PC/setup?

Comment: I just tried it and it **works ok for me.**  I create a new project.  Add a TODO line and verify that both TODO lines show up in task list.  Close the entire IDE.  reopen the solution, and without modifying the .cs file, I can see both TODO lines in the Task List.

Comment: Interesting info, @J'e , that sounds as if it could be my local setup, doesn't it

Comment: You could trying running it in safe mode using the `/SafeMode` option.  I don't know if this will help solve your issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022.

Comment: @J'e, tried but no joy, thanks again. Doing a "Visual Studio Installer"-> "Repair" seems to have cured the symptom fortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a "Visual Studio Installer" -> "Repair" seems to have cured the symptom so far fortunately. (That part took a while though and also demanded an O/S restart. Reinstalling one Extension and arranging desired IDE/Debug windows layout afterwards was easy.)

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me.  I have been using VS 2022 for a while, and today is the first time I've seen it.  Making a small code edit didn't change anything, but just closing and restarting VS did.

I have been clearing caches and cleaning solutions today.  I have also had both 2019 and 2022 open, but that hasn't caused a problem (that I've noticed) before.

Answer (score 0):

In the (hidden) .vs\ProjectEvaluation\ folder, deleting the older versions of the files .metadata.vx.y and .projects.vx.y of the project in question solved the problem for me.